# sudo jython ez_setup.py sudo: jython: command not found

Tags: python, jython, commcare

I am trying to set up CommCare using the following script:

https://github.com/dimagi/commcare-hq/wiki/Installing-Dependencies-on-Ubuntu-12.04

---

When I run the  following command:

```
sudo jython ez_setup.py
```

I get the  error:

> ```
> sudo: jython: command not found
> ```

I have followed the  steps of installing the jython jar file and it was installed successfully but I cannot use it. What should I do solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

first run below command

```
         sudo java -jar jython_installer-2.5.2.jar
```

When you type in jython, the shell looks for a program with that name in the PATH. You should either call the program with its full path:

```
   # ~ is an abbreviation for your homedir
   ~/jython2.5.2/bin/jython
```

or add the directory with the executable to your PATH:

```
    PATH=$HOME/jython2.5.2/bin:$PATH
```

If you want the latter to persist across terminal sessions, add it to your ~/.bashrc.

if above not works then try below:

Select '/usr/local/lib/jython', then create a symbol link of Jython to /usr/local/bin:

```
  sudo ln -s /usr/local/lib/jython/bin/jython /usr/local/bin/
```